# Log raw bytes of any primitive number to a file

Tags: java, logging

I'm in the process of developing a light-weight data/metrics logger for my robotics team. I need to be able to retrieve data from sensors or switches at any given point in time, and I want to make them any primitive number I want.

Currently, I have a protected `Loggable` interface which has a single method `Object getLogData()`. There are several public sub-interface for different primitive types. Each of them can be registered to the `Logger` (added to a `List<Loggable>`) to access data from while it is running.

This is the current, untested code for logging data from the `Loggable` classes:

```
loggables.forEach((loggable) -> {
    if (loggable instanceof ByteLoggable) {
        writer.write((Byte) loggable.getLogData());
    } else if (loggable instanceof ShortLoggable) {
        writer.writeShort((Short) loggable.getLogData());
    } else if (loggable instanceof IntLoggable) {
        writer.writeInt((Integer) loggable.getLogData());
    } else if (loggable instanceof LongLoggable) {
        writer.writeLong((Long) loggable.getLogData());
    } else if (loggable instanceof FloatLoggable) {
        writer.writeFloat((Float) loggable.getLogData());
    } else if (loggable instanceof DoubleLoggable) {
        writer.writeDouble((Double) loggable.getLogData());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown loggable type: " + loggable);
    }
});
```

This block seems very clunky to me - I feel like there is a much simpler way to do this that I can't think of. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is one in Java. There might be a library.

Comment: Use a wrapper with multiple log methods that take specific data types?

Comment: A visitor pattern might work here. Make the `writer` the visitor.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That seems like a feasible option. I'll try it out and post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @BoristheSpider, I used a visitor pattern (which was a foreign concept to me when I first started). It seemed to work out really well - I created a `LoggableVisitor` which handled relations with `Loggable`s. Next, I added a `logData(LoggableVisitor)` method to the `Loggable` interface. The code has not been tested yet, but it has cleaned it up quite a bit. Thanks again for introducing me to the visitor concept!

Comment: If you post the code you wrote, then it will show the transformation. It will also help people more in the future. And might even attract a few up votes... Admittedly, I would have make the `logData` method take a `writer` or, ideally, some `interface` it implements. But it depends on whether the `Loggable` should know about the `writer`.